# In Node v8 (v8.9.3 or above), commonjs require module create new context

Tags: node.js, requirejs, amd, commonjs

We are working on templating library with helpers (Dust.js), the helper library has below design pattern inside the codebase.

```
(function(root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd && define.amd.dust === true) {
    define(['dust-linkedin'], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = factory(require('dust-linkedin'));
    // module.exports = factory; // <<--- This is working on v8
  } else {
    factory(root.dust);
  }
}(this, function (dust) {
 ...
});
```

In node v6, exporting factory(require('dust-linkedin')) is working fine, but after switching to node v8 (v8.9.3) and we see helpers are not getting executed, changing **factory(require('dust-linkedin'))** to **factory** inside the helper library, things starts working.

In node v8, when require('dust-linkedin') does it create a new context/object because of which we are losing all our helpers? Is there any change in commonjs require behavior?

Comment: I've used dozens of libraries that use the UMD pattern. There was no issue moving from Node 6 to Node 8. Please edit your question to detail what it is you expect to happen, and what happens *instead*. If you get an exception, post the full stack trace. Actually, you should edit your question to allow people to reproduce the problem ([mcve]). The commented out code you say "works" is not doing the right thing.

Comment: Thanks Louis for pointing out, will modify the question

Comment: The code of [dust-helpers](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs-helpers/blob/master/dist/dust-helpers.js) has `module.exports.registerWith = factory;` after `module.exports = factory(require('dust-linkedin'));` but the code you show does not have it.

Comment: Yes! that changes we did it recently and Linkedin merged it. but we are now facing a similar issue with another helper @provide https://github.com/krakenjs/festucam/tree/master/src/helpers/data/provide

we tried doing the same changes with provide but its not working (we are debugging) https://github.com/krakenjs/festucam/pull/4

Comment: In provide, somehow factory(require('dustjs-linkedin')) is undefined

Comment: Fix the issue, here is the updated PR https://github.com/krakenjs/festucam/pull/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was fixed in the PR https://github.com/krakenjs/festucam/pull/4